# How to use MDX to calculate the difference between dates on seperate rows?

Tags: ssas, mdx, datediff, cubes

I am quite new to MDX and I need to write a query that gives me the day difference between two dates. The problem is that the dates exist on two different rows in my data. For example:

My Fact table:

```
SEAL | STARTDATE | PROCESS | FK_DATE_KEY  
1    | 2012-10-22|    A    | 20121022
1    | 2012-10-24|    B    | 20121024
2    | 2012-10-22|    A    | 20121022
2    | 2012-10-26|    B    | 20121026
```

What I need returned is :

```
SEAL | AGE_IN_DAYS
1    |      2
2    |      4
```

Please help.... I have a date dimension that relates to my FK_DATE_KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to `MDX`, you shouldn't try to do this problem using only `MDX`. This particular problem is much easier if you write it under `SQL` and use that data in your Analysis Services.

So, the easiest and nicest way to do this problem is to write a view which returns the same data you gave in your question. (`SEAL | AGE_IN_DAYS`)
Then you are able to insert these data in your Data Source View (if you choose 'new named query', you can fetch table-valued functions too, not only views and tables)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I another solution is to add the startdate as a float to the Fact table, then in my report I just use the lookup function between the two data sets (one for each process) and do a date difference on the floats casted as dates. Thanks a lot, much appreciated!